# Impossible to extract the whistle contour on PAMGuard

Tags: pamguard, whistles

[image: spectrogram]

It's impossible for me to extract the whistle contour with pamguard. I'm using ROCCA. I notice that the lowpass and highpass filters aren’t on all the spectrogram maybe it’s because of that ? Do you know how can I make the filter go on all of the spectrogram ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi Elise, welcome. Could you please provide us with some additional information so we can best help. Can you specify exactly which modules you are using in Pamguard and how exactly you are trying to apply the filters?